# The set of all natural numbers is closed under addition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I'm trying to prove the theorem described in the title, but my proof is so obvious I doubt it is sufficient.

Here's my way of proving it:

Definition of addition: Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be natural numbers.
We write $a + b = c$ if and only if there exist sets $A$ and $B$ such that a = equiv_class(A), b = equiv_class(B), $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and c = equiv_class($A \cup B$).

My Proof:
Let $A, B$ be subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ (natural numbers set). Since both are subsets of $N$ then their union will also be a subset of $N$. Let $c$ belong to $C = A \cup B$. Now $C$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, therefore $c$ is a natural number.

Is my proof so stupid it's funny?

What is the best way to prove this?

Comment: Depends on how 'foundational' your definitions are...?

Comment: What's your set of all natural numbers? $\omega$?

Comment: Maybe give your proof and we can tell you if it has any gaps?

Comment: You need to specify what you have available to work from.  What are your axioms?  How do you define the set of all naturals?

Comment: You most likely can't prove it. You can start from ZFC set theory, the Peano axioms, or treating the natural numbers as a ring, but in all cases the condition of closure is axiomatic.

Comment: Hint: consider what you have when you add $a$ stones to $b$ stones.

Comment: I updated the question with addition of my proof.

Comment: Your proof seems to confuse the notion of "the equivalence class of A" with the notion "member of A". In the definition of addition (in your question) c is the equivalence class of (A union B). In your attempted proof, c is an element of (A union B).

Comment: If a and b are natural numbers doesn't that mean that A and B are subsets of N?